# updating child's record,inserts a new record in master table

Tags: entity-framework-4, parent-child

I have two entities namely,

```
public class Employee
{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  public string value{get;set;}
  public int DepartmentID{get;set;}
  public  virtual Department department {get;set;}
}

public class Department
{
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

I am using repository pattern along with DTOs.I am using EF4 for accessing data from SQL server 2008.I am able to retrieve data from employee table along with referenced data.The problem is when i update a record in child table in the business logic,a new record is getting inserted in master table and then that records' ID is referenced in the child table.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: So the new record got a new ID?

Comment: yes.The new record got new ID

Comment: Show us how you update the record

Comment: I am mapping DTO to entity using value injector.Then i am inserting using,                   dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(Object);